# What should I have in my chameleon enclosure?

Tags: reptiles, enclosure, chameleons

I have a 6 month old Yemen Chameleon, she is doing well and is perfectly healthy. In my enclosure I have a large log that goes diagonal from one corner to the other. I then have leaves wrapped around them. I also have a water bowl at the bottom (even though I've seen online that they don't need one but the shop keeper insisted). My enclosure is 1.5ft by 3ft, it seems pretty empty and I want to add more stuff in but I don't know what.

I guess what I'm trying to ask is, what else could I add to my enclosure without it being crammed? What do chameleons like in their enclosures?

Answer (score 1):

Chameleons are arboreal - meaning they love to climb and be off the ground so you'll want as many horizontal surfaces and climbing areas as you can fit. I noticed you mention you put plants/leaves in there as well: I personally prefer to opt for the artificial vines/logs to prevent any rotting, make sure that you're only using plants that are non-toxic to your chameleon. You can get a full list of [safe plants](https://funwithlife.org/veiled-chameleon/habitat-enclosure/#Full_Safe_Plant_List) below.

If you haven't yet, you can also add a substrate. Most people go for simple newspaper or paper towels, though you can also add bark chips if you'd prefer. But the big focus should be on areas for him to climb on.